# Configure Twitter External Authentication in ASP.NET Core without Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, twitter, asp.net-core-mvc, twitter-oauth

I am trying to get User Access Token and Token Secret from Twitter sign in and then verify them from asp.net web api before storing user in my database.

I have already configured Cookie Authentication Without Identity for my Asp.net core MVC web application. Now I want to integrate (External/Social Authentication) Twitter, Facebook, Google in this app and I started with Twitter. I also found this link in Microsoft docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/social-without-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1

But the page is not to the point and the link provided for Twitter takes me back to the Twitter Login that uses Identity.
I have not configured Identity and I want to implement my own Social Login. What Can I do? Has anyone done it?

I tried to use client-side javascript but turns out Twitter does not allow it and throws a CORS error event though header Access-Control-Allow-Origin = "*" is set.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: it did its job when *taking you back to the Twitter Login*. That's the first step, it does not care if Twitter uses Identity or not. After the twitter logging-in successfully, you should be able to be logged-in on your web. That's not Identity at all, Identity here is when you explicitly configure it with `AddIdentity` and involve with all the Identity models (including the persistent store which is usually a database mapped by EFCore).